# What does this grep expression mean?

Tags: grep

```
\*.\?[A-Z]\?.*
```

This `grep` command is cryptic. I understand that it is supposed to search for uppercase commands.

Comment: You can take a look at - https://regex101.com/

Comment: We need to see the exact command you invoke. As it stands, the backslashes might be to protect '*' and '?' from shell expansion, or to keep grep from treating them as metacharacters.

Answer (score 2):

As a `grep` *standard* regular expression `\*.\?[A-Z]\?.*` means search for:

- a literal asterisk `*`
- followed by `zero or one of any character`
- followed by `zero or one of any character from A to Z inclusive`
- followed by `zero to any number of any characters` (to end of line in
  this case)

That is what it means, but the `.\?` and `[A-Z]\?`are rather meaningless (or at least redundant), as the `.*` will cater for *any* characters in those two character positions if either or both are not matched (present).

Comment: You missed the escapes on question marks. As it stands, expression searches for a `*[any character]?[capital letter]?[zero or more any chars]`. On the other hand, if the expression is not quoted and shell resolves those escapes, it's possibly invalid regex since first asterix isn't preceded by character. Not sure about that. Unless grep is smart enough to treat single unescaped asterix as a literal one.

Comment: The answer addresses question, which states that it is a regular expression, but I'm sure to OP has gott the drift about there being a difference regarding _quoted or not_ to the shell

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If you treat first escaped character ,`\*`, as literal and next two, `\?`s, as non-literal it can't be the correct search criteria. Or I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Aside from any shell interaction, `?` in grep's standrd regex is treated as a literal. eg. `printf %s\\n a '?' 'a?' | grep --color=always '?'`, though if `\?` is not preceded by anything which it can act upon as a _special_ `zero or one` regular expression modifier, then the `\?` is treated as a normal escaped character (ie. as the character itself). eg. `printf %s\\n a '?' 'a?' | grep --color=always '\?'` - as compared to `printf %s\\n a '?' 'a?' | grep --color=always 'a\?'`

Comment: I stand corrected. \? is the modifier (non-literal) version in standard grep regex and the opposite is true in extended regex which I was thinking in. Thanks for the clarification.